# Animating simple v-if directive in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rendering, frontend

Is it possible to animate, more specifically "fadeOut" a div when it is being removed/destroyed do to a `v-if` conditional?

I have the most basic conditional:

```
<template v-if="initProxy">
  <div class="page__boot">
  <div>
</template>
```

In my components `data` prop, when I set `initProxy` to false, I'd like to fadeOut the rendered div before its destroyed, rather than it just abruptly disappearing. I know I'm missing something so trivial... suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

You should follow this basic [example](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Single-Elements-Components)

```
<template>
  <transition name="fade">
    <div class="page__boot" v-if="initProxy">
    <div>
  </transition>
</template>
```

And adjust your animation:

```
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Also you can change duration for .fade-leave-active

Comment: I used the `v-if` directive on a `template` el for a reason. When using `v-if` directly on an element, it leaves a `<––––>` in the dom In place of the div when it is not there.

Comment: @JaredGarcia in that situation you should use v-show instead of v-if, and then it will render whole component but it is not visible and with v-if you have <––––> because component is not rendered. But still you should use <transition> as parent. So copy -> paste and instead of v-if use v-show.

Comment: i didn't want to use v-show because that keeps the element in the DOM. I want it removed